# GORM: automatically prefix each table name with the domain class namespace

Tags: hibernate, grails, naming-conventions, grails-orm, naming

I have separated all my domain classes into namespaces and I would like GORM to keep this separation at the DB level, using table prefixes.

For example:

```
auth.User  -> auth__user
auth.Group -> auth__group
auth.Role  -> auth__role
cms.Page   -> cms__page
cms.Post   -> cms__post
cms.Image  -> cms__image
```

I'm looking for a way to do that without having to write the table names inside each domain class.

I've gotten Hibernate to recognize a custom NamingStrategy, but alas the string I get passed to [classToTableName()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html#classToTableName%28java.lang.String%29) is only the short class name; the namespace is nowhere to be seen.

Is there a way to write a NamingStrategy that knows what the class namespace is? ([possibly not](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6077?focusedCommentId=59274&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-59274))

Is there some other automagic Grails thing I could try? Maybe some code that could be written once and applied to all domain classes?

I see that Grails has a `grails.gorm.table.prefix.enabled` settings for plugins, that somehows manages to prefix the plugin name to the tables. Can I use the same technique to add my namespaces? I looked in the sources, but I couldn't find the place where `grails.gorm.table.prefix.enabled` is read and applied.

Comment: Did you try static `mapping = { table 'your_custom_name' }` in the domain class? And also you may create your own plugin to get access to `grails.gorm.table.prefix.enabled`. If I've correctly understood your question.

Comment: Yes, I could write the mapping table in every class. But I'm looking for a generic solution to write once and forget about. Writing my own plugin is something I had not considered, but it could be an option, moving forward.

Comment: You may write your own annotation or AST for domain classes. But you must provide that your annotation/AST will run before grails AST.

Comment: Please look at theese three links [one](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2014/07/grails-goodness-custom-controller-class.html), [two](http://www.slideshare.net/gagana24/ast-transformation), [three](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/creating-custom-annotations-for-domain-classes-td4487250.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by using custom `NamingStrategy`.

For that you have put following line in DataSource.groovy

```
hibernate {
    ...
    naming_strategy = com.test.CustomNamingStrategy
}
```

And you have to extend `ImprovedNamingStrategy`

```
package com.test

import grails.util.Holders
import org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

/**
 * Created by ramsharan on 9/11/14.
 */
class CustomNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {
    String classToTableName(String className){
        Class clazz = Holders.grailsApplication.domainClasses.find { it.clazz.simpleName == className }.clazz
        String packageName = clazz.getPackage().getName()
        "${packageName}__${className.toLowerCase()}"
    }
}
```

I have used following two links as references :

[For Custom Naming Strategy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customNamingStrategy)

[For getting package name from class name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17088845/1610918)

Comment: It works! I guess this is the best we can do, given the Hibernate API. Thank you